# onclick Listener for custom listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am developing an android application with a custom list view ( with a single image and two text views)

The class mainactivity has ....

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String[] memetitles;
String[] memedesc;
ListView list;
int[] images = {R.drawable.angry_icon,R.drawable.happy_icon,R.drawable.kid_icon,R.drawable.scare_icon,R.drawable.warn_icon};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    memetitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    memedesc = res.getStringArray(R.array.notneed);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Itarray adapter = new Itarray(this,memetitles,memedesc,images);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    setTitle("Tamil Memer");
}
```

The class for combining two layouts into a single list view has

```
class Itarray extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Context context;
int[] image;
String[] tit1;
String[] tit2;
Itarray(Context c , String[] titles ,String[] notneed, int imgs[])
{
    super(c , R.layout.single_row,titles);
    this.context = c;
    this.image = imgs;
    this.tit1 = titles;
    this.tit2 = notneed;
}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.single_row , parent , false);
        }
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tit = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView des = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myImage.setImageResource(image[position]);
        tit.setText(tit1[position]);
        des.setText(tit2[position]);
        return row;
    }
```

}

The two layout files : 
(the one with the image and the textviews)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.itassistors.tmg.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="@string/simple"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/simple"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/happy_icon" />
```

(the one with the listview)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.itassistors.tmg.MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>
```

I want to know how and where to place the onClickListener() for this custom list view 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

**1)** Set the click listener in your **activity**:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            // Do your stuff here
        }

 });
```

**2)** Set the click listener in your **adapter**:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.single_row , parent , false);
        }
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tit = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView des = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myImage.setImageResource(image[position]);
        tit.setText(tit1[position]);
        des.setText(tit2[position]);
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Do your stuff here
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried this method ,but to my surprise it is showing an error for using row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: When I use it in the adapter class it throws an error like this...   The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Use View.OnClickListener() not DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

Comment: Now it is working.I used a galleryview in a layout.I want to use the images from the assets folder as the images of the gallery . Can you help me?

Comment: You shuld put your images in */res/drawable* why you put them in assets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in adapter you will to follow this code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    ViewHolderItem holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_item, null);
        View row = convertView;

        holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "ROW PRESSED");
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YourAction.class));
            }
        });

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;

}
```